# Excel - compare cells of columns and delete row if they contain partly the same value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, comparison

I try to delete rows of a CSV file, where two columns contain partly the same value, like this:

```
ColA                     ColB                 ColC       ColD
mydom/users/michael      mydom2\michael       blabla     false
mydom/users/julia        mydom2\sandra        blabla     true
mydom/users/charlie      mydom2\charlie       blabla     false
mydom/users/max          mydom2\albert        blabla     false
```

If ColA contains the same name after the last slash (e.g. michael) as ColB
after the backslash (like in row 1 and 3), then the whole row should be deleted.

Is there a way to use remove duplicates with special criteria? Need help with that, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey, sorry I know that, actually I was working on a script on my own but I wondered if I could do that in excel, that's why I posted the question. And in excel I only know the remove duplicates option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Powershell,

```
Select-String -n -path file.csv -Pattern "/([^/,]+).*\\\1" | select -exp Line
```

`-n` returns non-matching, pattern is conditions you want (with an extra check on CSV file's delimiter). Once tested, you can add `> new_file.csv` at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to solve the problem with regex but I'm new to that, so that was very helpful! I'm using a semikolon as csv delimiter, so I should change that part [^/,] to this [^/;] right? What is the ".*\\\1" part doing? Thanks alot!

Comment: Correct, use `;` instead. `.*` searches 0 or more (`*`) chars (`.`, any). `\\ `is the backslash, which needs a backslash to be escaped. `\1` is a backreference to content captured by parentheses: if you have "michael" after the slash, you need to have "michael" after the backslash.